# HTML5 Canvas layer to HTML/CSS code

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I've got a canvas on which I can add multiple layers (text and images), I use this to make templates. What I am trying to achieve at the end is that when I add a layer there will be a block of HTML/CSS created that contains the properties of the layer, these properties are:

- X
- Y
- Width
- Height
- Font
- Font-size
- Font-Color
- Angle
- Content

In the end I want to achieve that when I add a layer a block of code will be created and when I change any of the layers properties by for example moving it then the code should be changed aswell and when I change the code then the layer should change accordingly on the canvas.

I have searched alot for something like this but I wasn't able to find anything. If someone knows how I can do this (if it's even possible) it would be great!

A working example of my canvas can be found here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HvLDs (If it doesnt do anything when you've added a layer try refreshing)

Pastebins of the codes:
http://pastebin.com/uRqiKzGd
http://pastebin.com/CXF6DtyC

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong technology. HTML5 Canvas doesn't record the elements you add in the DOM, it's more of a 'Fire and Forget' technology. Once you've rendered it, you've lost it essentially.

If you look at SVG on the otherhand, each SVG item has a DOM representation that you can clearly see, manipulate and style using CSS. Layering SVG would be a much more appropriate approach to this problem than trying to use Canvas.

To illustrate, here's some example code to render a Canvas circle:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
      var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 70;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
      context.stroke();
</script>
```

The resultant DOM however just looks like:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

If you compare this to SVG, you've got the actual circle within the DOM:

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thnx for the explanation, I'll see what I can do with this.